# Formula required for inserting cut-off time

Tags: excel, time

[image]

I am developing an excel where timestamp needs to be added and if the timestamp goes beyond the specific time, then it should return a value says "Late" or else it should return "On-Time"

I tried 3 formulas but none of them works if the cut-off time is specified.

```
=IF(C2<TIME(5,10,0),"On-Time",IF(C2>=TIME(5,10,0),"Late","0"))

=IF(AND(C18>TIME(12,0,0),C18<TIME(12,0,0)),"Late","On-Time")

=IF(C2<E2,"On-Time","Late")
```

Please help me

"C" column is the place where timestamp is stamped. It is linked to sheet 1 where it is actually stamped and this is the backend sheet. Refer the image and E2 is for cut-off time.

Comment: What is in C2? How does the time stamp get "added"? Is the time stamp in C2? Imagine we cannot read your mind. Imagine we cannot see your screen and your data layout. Please edit your question and provide more detail.  Mock up the desired result manually. Post a screenshot of that or explain it in words. Then post a comment to alert the followers of your question.

Comment: Please look through

Comment: can you please activate a valid Excel license before we continue on this journey?

Comment: After that, please explain: the cell address of the result cell, the expected result in the result cell, the logic in plain English words that leads to that result. Edit your question and post a comment when you have done that.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation :

```
=IF(C2<TIME(5,10,0),"On-Time",IF(C2>=TIME(5,10,0),"Late","0"))
=IF(C2<E2,"On-Time","Late")
```

TIME(5,10,0) is 5 AM !, so the result is correct.

```
=IF(AND(C18>TIME(12,0,0),C18<TIME(12,0,0)),"Late","On-Time")
```

if this is the formula defined in F18. The result is correct.

just work with 24-hours convention and you are good to go. Unless.. your statement :

> none of them works if the cut-off time is specified.

have a description not viewable/mentioned in the screenshot shared. (:

hope that helps.